# Hide loader (spin) in struts2

Tags: css, struts2, loader

My web application (struts2) queries are often heavy and a considerable time is needed for a response.

I added some simple (just an html DIV and some CSS) spinning tops of waiting after action calls.   [*a whirligig like this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsgvI.png)

The spin rotates and when the action target is reached a new jsp is loaded and the spin disappears.

The problem arises when the action called is an action to download data like excel file (and I suppose, even if not yet tried, for pdf, file uploads etc.. in such cases new JSP don't needed to be loaded).

I can't find a way to stop or hide the spin when loading is completed.

I tried to stop the spinner using onblur event (applied to the spin div, to the container div, to the whole window etc..) when the window started downloading files.

So, I suppose the system window while loading files is not considered by the browser like a true window and so the event "onblur" is meaningless!

Finally, how can I hide the whirligig when response is started receiving mean when excel file is created, or simply when the system loading window is closed (or open )?

Comment: More generally, the problem can be defined in this way: how can I set display = none to  DIV?

Comment: no sudgestion? if another way exists to obtain what I need (insead of div + css) that's ok!

Comment: How did you download data? Post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your download action to two actions. The first one should return a javascript on success and and second one, step2, action should return the stream on success like below:

step1.jsp

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
closeBoxWait(previous_boxWait);
window.location = '<s:url namespace="/" action="step2"/>';
}); </script>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="exportExcelBill" 
    class="jj.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
    method="exportBillToExcel">

    <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
    <result name="login">timeout.jsp</result>

    <result name="success">step1.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="step2" 
    class="jj.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
    >

    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${reportFile}"</param>
        <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

premise - I hope to have got it right and that this is one of those cases where it is allowed to add a reply.
premise2 - I'm not a magician in Struts2 (but that's already clear, isn't?)

Thanx Yasser, I tried your precious suggestion but I've a hard time:
this is  my new struts.xml

```
    <action name="exportExcelBill" 
        class="it.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
        method="exportBillToExcel">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
        <result name="login">timeout.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">jsp/common/intermeanExcel.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="completeExport" 
        class="it.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
        method="completeExport">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
        <result name="login">timeout.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${reportFile}"</param>
            <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

this is intermeanExcel.jsp:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/common.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <%@ include file="./warningwait.jsp" %>

     <script> 
         $(document).ready(function() {
                                        closeBoxWait(previous_boxWait);
                                        window.location = '<s:url namespace="/" action="completeExport"/>';
                                    }); 
    </script>   
</body>
```

I added too a row (the second last) to the original method (exportBillToExcel) in order to place in session the data stream

```
public String exportBillToExcel() {
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet(categ);
    try {
```

etc... etc... I omit the - unnecessary for this question - body of the method that was working well, when stood alone, etc...

```
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
===>    session.put("tmpstream", inputStream);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

in order to recover it in the new method

```
public String completeExport() {
    inputStream = (InputStream)session.get("tmpstream");
    logger.info("completeExport() - inputStream="+inputStream);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

but this is the error log (even if -first row- the stream is not null):

```
01/02 07:30:07| INFO [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (BillAction.java:704) - completeExport() - inputStream=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@11d1921
01/02 07:30:07| ERROR [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (CommonsLogger.java:34) - Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified f
or this action.
01/02 07:30:07| ERROR [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (CommonsLogger.java:38) - Exception occurred during processing request: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Chec
k the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:271)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
```

where I'm wrong?

PS - hiding of the spinner works! thanx!